# Get enum value from enum type and ordinal

Tags: java, reflection, enums

```java
public <E extends Enum> E decode(java.lang.reflect.Field field, int ordinal) {
    // TODO
}
```

Assuming `field.getType().isEnum()` is `true`, how would I produce the enum value for the given ordinal?

Comment: `Field` is not an enum. I have updated the question to clarify that, although I thought it would be apparent from the tags.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
field.getType().getEnumConstants()[ordinal]
```

suffices.  One line; straightforward enough.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Except that the whole expression is within the scope of `Field` and `Class` xD

Answer (score 4):

```
ExampleTypeEnum value = ExampleTypeEnum.values()[ordinal]
```

Comment: Please see comment in question.

Answer (score 3):

To get what you want you need to invoke `YourEnum.values()[ordinal]`. You can do it with reflection like this:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E decode(Field field, int ordinal) {
    try {
        Class<?> myEnum = field.getType();
        Method valuesMethod = myEnum.getMethod("values");
        Object arrayWithEnumValies = valuesMethod.invoke(myEnum);
        return (E) Array.get(arrayWithEnumValies, ordinal);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

### UPDATE

As @LouisWasserman pointed in his comment there is much simpler way

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> E decode(Field field, int ordinal) {
    return (E) field.getType().getEnumConstants()[ordinal];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think I can get past doing something like `return (Enum[])field.getType().getMethod("values").invoke(null))[ordinal];`.

Comment: Not that it matters *that* much, but the type should be `<E extends Enum<E>>`

Comment: Much simpler: `field.getType().getEnumConstants()[ordinal]`

Comment: @LouisWasserman if you move your comment to an answer I will accept that one as that is obviously the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to title, suggest

```
public <E extends Enum> E decode(Class<?> enumType, int ordinal) 
{
   return enumType.getEnumConstants()[ordinal];
}
```

to be called by

```
YourEnum enumVal = decode(YourEnum.class, ordinal)
```